# IIS 7 or iis8 -- authentication redirect for expiring passwords - replacement for authexpiredurl in iis 6?

Tags: authentication, iis, iis-8

We have a windows2012 server/IIS 8 running an ASP application using basic authentication that was migrated from IIS 6.  When an account with an expired password is entered the page is not re-directed, on any 401, including 401.5 which is what the server shows by default.

in IIS 6 this was set on the metabase property authexpiredurl="/..../"

There is no mapping to iis 7 or 8 because that config and related auth configs are deprecated, and I'm not finding a simple solution.  What is a good alternative replacement for this functionality?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We opened a ticket with MS to confirm I wasnt missing anything in my research and they actually have no replacement in IIS 7/8 for this functionality.

They confirmed they deprecated it (even though they still "fully" support basic and windows authentication in IIS 7 and 8), and the only way to validate expired passwords now is to use a custom HTTP module.

They suggested one on codeplex that was created as part of the also popular need for the replacement of IISADMPWD:
http://iisadmpwdhttpmodule.codeplex.com/releases